Restoring a clonezilla Image of two independent Disks on a computer with only one Haarddisk with two partitions
My system is seated on 2 Disks:
/dev/nvme0n1p2 239152936  88597432 138334364   40% /
/dev/nvme0n1p1    101158      4914     96244    5% /boot/efi
/dev/sda2      927306756 520268880 359859552   60% /home
Can i proceed like shown in
Clonezilla restoring to a different partition
to get my clonezilla mage save on the other Computer, which has only one (suitable partitoned) Harddisk
or do i have to perform some more steps before or after these steps?
Regards
Rainer

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Most new systems are gpt partitioned. And GUIDs must match in primary, backup & partition table. So restoring one partition, may not have correct GUID. I normally suggest new clean install & restore data from you normal backup. Proves backup has everything you need. After install, I have rsync'd /home & data from desktop to external SSD to make a fully bootable system on external SSD.
